# Passing multiple commands to gnome-terminal from a script

Tags: command-line, bash

My bash-script is not run in a terminal, but opens a terminal at runtime to ask for user input (sudo password). I would like to tell the user in this terminal what the script is trying to do. First, here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This should install: Qt Linguist, lrelease

#for Qt Linguist
dpkg-query -l qt4-dev-tools
if echo $? == 0; then
 check1=1
fi

#for lrelease
dpkg-query -l qt4-default
if echo $? == 0; then
 check2=1
fi

echo $check1
echo $check2

if [ $check1 = 1 ] && [ $check2 = 1 ];then
 gnome-terminal -x sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools qt4-default
fi
$SHELL
```

This opens a terminal with this:

```
[sudo] password for "username":
```

But I would like to have:

```
qt4-dev-tools and qt4-default are missing. Now trying to install.
[sudo] password for "username":
```

How do I get this when starting the terminal with `gnome-terminal -x`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had trouble passing multiple commands to gnome-terminal before, too. Something like this is what I eventually ended up using in my case:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "echo \"qt4-dev-tools and qt4-default are missing. Now trying to install.\" && sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools qt4-default"
```

Hope it works for you.