# Double-click on .sh file to open terminal and execute series of commands in it?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to double click on a file that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#Mount USB Jump, Copy files to it, Unmount it.
[open terminal (so that I can see what 's going on)]
pmount /dev/sdc JUMP
sleep 2s
cp -p -u source/path/ destination/path/
read -p "Press enter to unmount Jump or ctrl c to abort."
pumount /dev/sdc
[close terminal]
```

The two lines I don't know how to write are [open terminal] and [close terminal]
Anyone knows how to do this?

Edit:
Many thanks folks, I bundled your input together and eventually got there.

I double-click on the .sh file that says: 'terminal -hold -e /path/to/JumpBkp.sh' and it opens a terminal and gives me the whole rundown onscreen.

It was cool to receive so much input in so little time. Many thanks again.

2nd Edit:
I've come up with an option that makes it even sweeter. I post it in case anyone bumps into this thread.

```
terminal -hold -e bash '/path/to/JumpBkp.sh'
```

The 'bash' spares me of that darn: "Warning: Could not find '/path/to/file.sh', starting '/bin/bash' instead.  Please check your profile settings."

Cheerio!

Answer (score 6):

`gnome-terminal -e command`

or

`terminal -e command`

See Here for details:
[How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes commands in them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)

Also of interest: [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-bash-scripts-in-nautilus)

And some creativity with passing multiple commands: [Passing multiple commands to gnome-terminal from a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351097/passing-multiple-commands-to-gnome-terminal-from-a-script)