# How do I make a file default opened by the terminal on double click?

Tags: unity, command-line

This is my file, which I saved as eclipse-start.sh

https://gist.github.com/Meai1/d02bc20836f97f6ecb3e

I also made it executable. But it always starts in gedit??

Comment: why do I need to do that?

Comment: you mean for all the files.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows and http://askubuntu.com/questions/394897/double-click-on-sh-file-to-open-terminal-and-execute-series-of-commands-in-it